# jQuery - Animate overflow?

Tags: jquery, html, overflow, jquery-animate

How can I use jQuery to animate a div overflow?

Normally if I wish to animate a div element I'd use something like this:

```
$("div").animate({height: 200}, "slow");
```

And that works great! but if the content of the div exceeds 200px, the content is cut off at 200px
is there a way to keep animation running till the end of the content?

Answer (score 4):

You can ask the `<div>` how tall it wants to be by asking for its [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight) and then animate to that height instead of a fixed height:

```
var height = $('div').prop('scrollHeight');
$('div').animate({ height: height }, 'slow');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/WBcME/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid; min-height: 400px;">
    hi<br>
    Here's some content<br>
    Here's some more
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("div").animate({minHeight: '1px',  }, "slow");
```

I don't think it'd work in IE6 - but who uses that anyway eh?

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jameszaghini/SCJpZ/